# Redirecting with js code in event

Tags: jquery, asp.net, redirect, settimeout

Inside an event in my code behind file I want to run a script that redirect the user to a specific page after 3 seconds. I understand that I can use the Page.ClientScript line below with a setTimeout, but what I need help with is what to actually put inside the setTimeout statement to get this works?

At the bottom is the code line I use for redirecting, that I want to replace with the Page.ClientScript line.

Thanks in advance!

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "redirect", "setTimeout('???', 3000);", true);

Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/Edit.aspx?id={0}", movie.MovieID), false);
```

NOTE: I have tried the following without any luck:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "setTimeout('top.location.href = " + String.Format("~/Edit.aspx?id={0}", movie.MovieID) + "', 3000);", true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setTimeout("top.location.href = 'TARGET'", 3000);
```

Replace TARGET with the URL you want to redirect to.

You can build the target URL dynamically from the codebehind:

```
string targetUrl = String.Format("/Edit.aspx?id={0}", movie.MovieID);
string javaScript = "setTimeout(\"top.location.href = '" + targetUrl + "'\", 3000);";

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "redirect", javaScript, true);
```

Comment: Thanks. Okey, but how to I put in the dynamically number that's a part of the url (movieID)?

Comment: I tried: Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "setTimeout('top.location.href = " + String.Format("~/Edit.aspx?id={0}", movie.MovieID) + "', 3000);", true); but it doesn't seem to work :/

Comment: Thanks. Strange enough nothing happens when compiling the code. I've debugged and it compiles, but as I said nothing happens?

Comment: @JasonCraig, I had a syntax error in my JavaScript, try the updated code it should work now.